need solve"from Package1" "import Module2 error
Hello guys when I try to import modules from packages that isn't working this always told me this error message:
no module named: 'Package1'
Looking at my project structure there is no uncorrectly structure packages or modules
Project structure
Project
-Package1
-init.py
-Module1.py
-Module2.py
-Package2
-init.py
-Module3.py
-Module4.py
There is my project structure and I still cannot import modules from packages in any Project folder and I really need this function because some of my important projects folders import modules from packages.
There is my Module2 Python code
def function1():
        print('this is function1 from module1 in package1')

And there is my my module4 Python code
from Package1 import Module2

Module2.function1()

I've made lot of google research and I've found nothing. I've also made multiples youtube research and it doesn't work and now I'm trying to have expert advertise on forum so please feel free to let me know if you have some idea about what happen with my project.
thank alot to anybody who want to help me

Your project structure should look like this:
├── main.py
└── package1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module1.py
    └── module2.py

The package init file should be named __init__.py, not init.py. It's fine if it's blank. This tells Python that the subdirectory is a package. It's also recommended that everything be lowercase, as Python is caps-sensitive.
module1.py
def function1():
    print('this is function1 from module1 in package1')

module2.py
def function2():
        print('this is function2 from module2 in package1')

main.py
from package1 import module1, module2
from package1.module1 import function1 # If you don't have an overlapping function name

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    module1.function1() # from the first import statement
    module2.function2() # from the first import statement
    function1() # from the second import statement

Note that you can import the functions in different ways. The first one imports both modules in one line, but you'll have to use the full path to refer to the function, i.e., module1.function1. The second approach imports the specific function into your namespace, so you can just call function1.
Output
% python ./main.py 
this is function1 from module1 in package1
this is function2 from module2 in package1
this is function1 from module1 in package1

